# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-2

i am doing screen change like this iam listing for stream and when it emit i change the screen

```
 @override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();

     appBloc.error.listen((data) {
     _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new 
        Text(data)));
    });

     appBloc.success.listen((_) => goToDashBoardScreen(context));

}
```

and doToDashBoardScreen look like this

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new SlideRightRoute(widget: 
DashBoardScreen()));
```

but i am getting error like this but i change the page.

```
22:05:02.446 3 info flutter.tools E/flutter (13216): NoSuchMethodError: 
The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.
22:05:02.446 4 info flutter.tools E/flutter (13216): Receiver: null
22:05:02.446 5 info flutter.tools E/flutter (13216): Tried calling: 
ancestorStateOfType(Instance of 'TypeMatcher<NavigatorState>')
22:05:02.446 6 info flutter.tools E/flutter (13216): #0      
Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:48:5)
22:05:02.446 7 info flutter.tools E/flutter (13216): #1      
Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1270:19)
22:05:02.446 8 info flutter.tools E/flutter (13216): #2      
Navigator.pushReplacement 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:952:22)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your widget has most likely been removed from the tree. Therefore it doesn't have a `context` anymore.

The problem being, you forgot to unsubscribe to your `Stream`. Therefore even after being removed from the tree, your widget still attempts to update.

A solution would be to unsubscribe on `dispose` call:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    streamSubscription = Bloc.of(context).myStream.listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it solved the problem! thanks. i was wondering didChangeDependencies will solve it but it didn't . when to use initState vs didChangeDependencies ??

Comment: do you know how to fix ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097660/call-a-method-from-another-class-flutter

Answer (score 4):

**Problem** : It was the wrong context passed to a child widget.

**Solution** : After passing the Build method context which was the correct context to pass to the child widget my issue was resolved.