# Why it is showing 'The method 'rootAncestorStateOfType' was called on null' in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Am getting this kind of error in flutter.
May I know how can I solve it.

```
    I/flutter (23411): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'rootAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
I/flutter (23411): Receiver: null
I/flutter (23411): Tried calling: rootAncestorStateOfType(Instance of 'TypeMatcher<NavigatorState>')
```

Sometime it won't happen, sometime it is throwing error and my progress bar just looping only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130648/nosuchmethoderror-the-method-ancestorstateoftype-was-called-on-null

Comment: @JohnJoe It's because two progress bar I think

Comment: @SunishaSindhu Could you please post sample code that all defined in one single main.dart  to reproduce your problem? That would be great for any one to help you easily. Also add expected and actual output.